# A special playing technique for harmonics as seen in Sungha's Cover of Creep

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar, strumming

I am wondering what Sungha is doing in his Cover of Creep at around [1m43s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htTPcxckjf0#t=1m43s) and the same at [around 2m17s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htTPcxckjf0#t=2m17s). It sounds like he is playing some kind of harmonic. In the tabs ([for example this one](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/s/sungha_jung/creep_tab.htm)) it is indicated that he is playing at the 7th fret a harmonic, but that is not what he is doing as is clearly visible from the video.

So how does he achieve this sound, where is he creating the harmonic, and also where is the string plucked (he seems to do this all with his strumming hand, but I am not sure how)?

Comment: Check out Eddy van Halens guitar work for how far that technique could be taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one node to find harmonics at. The 7th fret placing of a finger to produce the harmonic is also available at the 19th fret position. It appears that he touches the string there, instead of 7th fret, with a thumb and plucks with finger. Some touch with finger and pluck with thumb (of the same hand...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have other examples of this technique, and maybe some tutorials?

Comment: This technique is often called a pinch harmonic in guitar terms.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks for the addition. Can't believe I forgot that. Can also be played as a tapped harmonic, hitting the string down onto something solid underneath - like the fretwire.